# Let users change their Password in Drupal 6 WITHOUT having to type email in

Tags: 6, users

On Drupal 6, When a user goes to 'edit' their account, they must also enter their email to be able to change the password. Is it possible to populate the email field with their stored address to avoid this?

Comment: I wonder how you got the email field blank. As far as I remember it was always populated to me.

Comment: Interesting, It's got 'Enter your email address' in it, under user/*uid*/edit

Comment: Long time since I was really using D6. Will point ex-coworker at this question, he is still using it at some places as far as I know.

Comment: @Mołot you've solved it for me.. I checked some javascript files and found some mail function a previous developer had implemented, which was clearing the email field out. Big thx!

Comment: Please post it as an answer :)

Comment: I can't answer due to low rep.

Comment: You will after some time. Comment @Mołot then to let me see it then.

Comment: @molot The problem was an old email removal function in our primary .js file, placed by an old developer. So people should double check this!